# Особиста чи особова справа?

Tags: прикметники

Учора у [відеосюжеті ТСН](https://tsn.ua/ukrayina/viyskkomati-pochali-stvorennya-yedinogo-vseukrayinskogo-reyestru-prizovnikiv-919368.html) про створення всеукраїнського цифрового реєстру призовників журналістка вжила вислів **`особисті справи`** у контексті кадрової документації.

Проаналізувавши значення обох слів із паронімічної пари в СУМ:

[ОСОБО́ВИЙ, а, е.](http://sum.in.ua/s/osobovyj)

[ОСОБИ́СТИЙ, а, е.](http://sum.in.ua/s/osobystyj),

а також коротке пояснення в підручнику [Українська мова за професійним спрямуванням - Шевчук С.В., Клименко І.В.](http://pidruchniki.com/1281041940606/dokumentoznavstvo/paronimi)

> **`Особистий` - `особовий`**
>
> **`Особистий`** - який є власністю окремої особи, безпосередньо належить їй, персональний; який безпосередньо стосується певної особи:
>   *особисті речі*, *особиста охорона*, *особисті уподобання*.
>
> **`Особовий`** - який стосується особи; відкритий на окрему особу: *особове посвідчення*, *особовий склад*, ***особова справа***, *особовий рахунок*

я сформулювала для себе просте пояснення, що **`особистий`** стосується ***приватної*** сфери, а **`особовий`** - ***соціальної***. При цьому **справа** може бути як **особовою**, так і **особистою**, в залежності від означеного контексту. Втім, у контексті діловодства - ***особова справа***.

Та все ж хотілося би почути більш професійну аргументацію. Є така?

Comment: Мені здається, що особовий — це коли підкреслюється належність/відношення до конкретної особи на противагу можливій належності/відношення до іншої особи, а особистий — це коли підкреслюється належність/відношення до особи на противагу спільності. Особовий = «Івана, а не Федора», особистий = «чийсь, а не колективу». Тобто я в цілому згоден з тим, що Ви написали, але сформулював би трішки по-іншому. Особистий — це саме **відмежування** від соціального/офіційного/колективного, а особовий — що має чіткий стосунок до конкретної особи (але необов'язково відмежування від соціальної ролі).

Comment: @Sasha, цілком погоджуюсь із Вами. Для себе сформулювала спрощений варіант пояснення)

Comment: @Sasha, ось ще Є.Д.Чак у роботі ["Складні випадки українського слововживання"](http://litmisto.org.ua/?p=21178) резюмує так: **"Взагалі для практичного користування можна зробити такий висновок: *особовий* вживається для передачі окремого, але певною мірою стереотипного, неіндивідуалізованого; *особистий* – індивідуальний, той, що стосується індивідуума."**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Досить зрозуміло пояснює Є.Д.Чак у посібнику ["Складні випадки українського слововживання"](http://litmisto.org.ua/?p=21178).

> **Особистий, особовий.**
>
> Дуже часто ці слова плутають: кажуть «особистий склад військової
>   частини» (треба особовий), «особові речі учня школи-інтернату» (треба
>   особисті).
>
> А як правильно сказати – ***особиста* чи *особова* справа**,
>   ***особисті* чи *особові* рахунки**?
>
> Виявляється, що **можливі обидва словосполучення, але кожне з них
>   треба вживати у певному контексті**.
>
> ***`Особиста справа`*** – **це справа, яка стосується певної особи, зумовлюється її власним бажанням і діями**. Наприклад, «*Мати вважала,
>   що одруження сина – його особиста справа*».
>
> ***`Особова справа`*** – **це документ про об’єктивні дані людини, який зберігається в установі; папка, в якій лежать документи кожного
>   працівника в установі.** Наприклад, «*У нового начальника відділу
>   кадрів усі особові справи були в зразковому порядку*».
>
> ***`Особовий рахунок`*** – **це рахунок певної особи в ощадній касі і картка, в якій відбито рух грошей (надходження і видачу); у
>   бухгалтерії домоуправління – картка квартиронаймача, в якій робляться
>   записи про нарахування плати за квартиру й комунальні послуги**.
>
> ***`Особисті рахунки`*** – **взаємини, що склалися між певними особами**.
>
> ***`Особистий`*** **вживаємо, коли йдеться про людську індивідуальність, особистість, про те, що стосується окремої людини,
>   її долі, життя, почуттів, переживань і т. д**. «*Але з кожною годиною,
>   як це буває в молодості, він все більше переконувався, що вже не
>   матиме свого особистого щастя*» (М. Стельмах). «…*В інших могло бути
>   щось не гаразд в особистому житті, і тоді вони мали право скаржитись,
>   вимагати співчуття і допомоги. У Воронцова мусило бути завжди все
>   гаразд, і було б дивно почути, що він на щось скаржиться: адже це
>   Воронцов*» (О. Гончар). «*Тут товариство основувалося не лише на
>   особистій симпатії і приятельській підмозі, а охоплювало ширші круги –
>   спільності по думці й прагненню до одної мети*» (Н. Кобринська).
>
> Дуже поширене в сучасній мові словосполучення ***`особовий склад`***
>   **на позначення людського складу військових з’єднань, навчальних закладів, персоналу військових установ**. «*Начальник училища,
>   привітавшися і скомандувавши «вільно», звернувся до особового складу
>   училища з короткою промовою*» (І. Багмут).
>
> Прикметник ***`особовий`*** вживається також як **граматичний
>   термін**: *особовий займенник, особові закінчення дієслів, особові
>   речення*.
>
> Взагалі для практичного користування можна зробити такий **висновок**:
>   ***`особовий`*** вживається для передачі **окремого, але певною мірою стереотипного, неіндивідуалізованого**; ***`особистий`*** –
>   **індивідуальний, той, що стосується індивідуума**. На перший погляд може видатися, що словосполучення особова справа як сукупність
>   анкетних і документальних даних випадає з цього плану. Насправді це не
>   так: особових справ багато, вони однакові формою (містять відповіді на
>   ті самі анкетні запитання), хоч відрізняються біографічними даними
>   (багато в чому й вони можуть збігатися, коли, наприклад, маємо справу
>   із спеціальним контингентом); особиста справа характеризується
>   особливим, незвичайним змістом і стосується тільки певної особи.

В [Уроках державної мови (з газети «Хрещатик»)](http://slovopedia.org.ua/30/53394/26148.html) ще звертається увага на особливості вживання схожого за значенням прикметника **власний**.

> **1. Чи тотожні прикметники *`власний`*, `особистий`, *`особовий`*?**
>
> Тотожними їх назвати не можна. Як наголошується в посібнику “Культура
>   мови на щодень”, значення цих лексем часто плутають, утворюючи
>   неправильні словосполучення. В одній з радіореклам прозвучало навіть
>   таке: вишні в особистому соку, а по-українському треба сказати: вишні
>   у власному соку.
>
> Правильні вислови: **маю *`власний`* будинок**, **маю *`власну`* думку**,
>   але **подаю *`особистий`* приклад**, **бажаю щастя в *`особистому`*
>   житті**; в діловій мові вживаємо словосполучення ***`особова`* справа**,
>   ***`особове`* посвідчення**, ***`особовий`* склад**; у граматиці є термін ***`особові`* займенники**.
>
> Різний зміст передають вислови ***`власний`* автомобіль** (тобто
>   **належний певній особі**) й ***`особистий`* автомобіль** (**визначений певній особі для службового користування**).
>
> Різні прикметники ставимо з іменником рахунок: ***`особовий`* рахунок**
>   – **у банку**, **відрядження беруть за *`власний`* рахунок**, а
>   **зводять з кимось *`особисті`* рахунки**.
>
> Синонімічні вислови на зразок: **дати щось комусь у *`власні`* руки** і
>   **дати щось комусь *`особисто`* в руки**; **з’явитися *`особисто`*** і розмовно-знижений **з’явитися *`власною`* персоною**.